# Erro ao rodar o docker-compose up para subir o traefik

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Após montar o docker-compose.yml da seguinte forma:

```
version: '3'

services:
    proxy:
        image: traefik
        command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
        networks:
            - webgateway
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
networks:
    webgateway:
        driver: bridge
```

Tento iniciar o container com o comando:

```
docker-compose up
```

Porém obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Creating network "traefik_webgateway" with driver "bridge"
Creating traefik_proxy_1 ... done
Attaching to traefik_proxy_1
proxy_1  | 2019/09/23 00:18:38 command traefik error: invalid node traefik: no child
traefik_proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

Tentei criar um arquivo chamado traefik.toml para espelhar no container com o seguinte conteudo:

```
# traefik.toml
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
```

Porém também tive o erro:

```
Creating network "traefik_webgateway" with driver "bridge"
Creating traefik_proxy_1 ... done
Attaching to traefik_proxy_1
proxy_1  | 2019/09/23 00:23:55 command traefik error: read /traefik.toml: is a directory
traefik_proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

Já tentei diversas vezes iniciar o traefik mas todas sem êxito. Segui [este tutorial da Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-18-04) e obtive também o erro:

```
2019/09/23 00:16:46 command traefik error: field not found, node: entrypoint
```

OBS: Experimentei em 4 máquinas diferentes, todas as vezes obtendo erros parecidos:

- No Windows com o Docker desktop
- No Ubuntu a partir do WSL (No windows)
- No Ubuntu 18 limpo em uma máquina criada no AMI da Amazon
- Em uma máquina pré-configurada pela BITNAMI com a MEAN stack

Comment: você chegou a dar uma olhada nessa receita aqui? -> https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik

Answer (score 0):

[Resolvido]
O que fiz:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http,ws"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```